# Filter in list page associated with other model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Using Rails 4 and Ruby 2.2, I have Subject list page where I need to add the filter for subject's name, username, active and books associated with the subject. All the three model i.e

> Subject, Book and User

are associated as below:

> user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subjects, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :books, dependent: :destroy
end
```

> book.rb

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :subject, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :images, dependent: :destroy
end
```

> subject.rb

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :books
  validates :name, presence: true,
                length: { minimum: 3 }


  def self.names(name)
    subject = all
    subject = subject.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{name}%")
    return subject
  end


  def self.actives(active)
    subject = all
    subject = subject.where("active = ?", "%#{active}%")
    return subject
  end


  def self.usernames(username)
    user = all
    user = user.where("username LIKE ?", "%#{username}%")
    return user
  end

end
```

Now I am trying to make filter on the subject list page with the following column

> 1. Username(Drop Down from User table)
> 2. Subject name(text field from subject table)
> 3. Active(Drop Down from subject table)
> 4. Has books (Check Box, association with books, if checked display only those subjects which is having books)

I have my index for subject as follows:

> subjects_controller.rb

```
def index

   @subjects = Subject.page(params[:page]).per(10)
   @users = User.all
   @subjects = @subjects.names(params[:name]) if params[:name].present?
   @subjects = @subjects.actives(params[:active]) if params[:active].present?
   @users = @users.usernames(params[:username]) if params[:username].present?
end
```

and my

> index.html.erb

as:

```
<h1>Listing Subjects</h1>
<%= link_to 'New Subject', new_subject_path %>

<%= form_tag subjects_path, :method=> "get" do %>

  <%= label_tag :username, "Username" %>
  <%= select_tag :username, options_from_collection_for_select(User.all, "id", "username", username) %>

  <%= label_tag :name, "Subject Name"%>
  <%= text_field_tag :name %>


  <%= label_tag :active, "Active" %>
  <%= select_tag :active, options_for_select([['Active', true], ['Inactive', false]]) %>


  <%= submit_tag "submit" %>
  <%= link_to "Clear Search", request.path, class:"cancel-button" %>
<% end %>


<div id="subjects"><%= render "index" %></div>

<%= paginate @subjects %><br>
```

My Console log is as:

```
Started GET "/subjects?utf8=%E2%9C%93&username=11&name=&active=false&commit=submit" for ::1 at 2016-04-19 10:20:06 +0530
Processing by SubjectsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "username"=>"11", "name"=>"", "active"=>"false", "commit"=>"submit"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = ?  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 11]]
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`
  Subject Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `subjects`.* FROM `subjects` WHERE (active = '%false%') LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
  Rendered subjects/_index.html.erb (5.1ms)
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `subjects` WHERE (active = '%false%')
  Rendered subjects/index.html.erb within layouts/application (34.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 99ms (Views: 94.1ms | ActiveRecord: 2.1ms)
```

Questions:

1. How can I have username column associated with each book in filter list
2. How to make filter list for has books or not as radio button?
3. How the active for subject(boolean datatype) list will work ?
4. How the checkbox for books availability can be done, means, if checkbox is marked I need to show only those subject having books.

Let me know if I need to provide more details

Comment: Can you log and share what you are getting in `params[:username]` ?

Comment: You have 3 params on which you want your search to work `user(name)`, `subject(active or not)` and `book(name)` and you want end results as books which fall into the criteria as per these params right ?

Comment: Then kindly explain a bit & i will propose a solution in accord.

Comment: @MuhammadYawarAli  1. Need to search on username,need to search on subject name, Need to search on boolean value whether the subject is active or not, and whether the subject has any books (check box). if it is check only show those subject having books or else not. let me know if I need to give more information